# Not able to compile own-client build

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5

Getting following error while building ownclient project

```
Could NOT find Doxygen (missing: DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
CMake Error at admin/osx/CMakeLists.txt:14 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package "Qt5" that is compatible with the requested version "5.6".

  The following configuration files were considered but not accepted:
     C:/Qt/Qt5.5.1/5.5/mingw492_32/lib/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake, version: 5.5.1
```

And if I compile this project using a version above 5.5 then this error occurs

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.13.2\5.13.2\mingw73_32\lib\cmake\Qt5WebKitWidgets\Qt5WebKitWidgetsConfig.cmake:15: 
    error: The imported target "Qt5::WebKitWidgets" references the file "C:/Qt/Qt5.13.2/5.13.2/mingw73_32/include/QtWebKitWidgets" but this file does not exist.
```

Comment: The log indicates that the application needs Qt 5.6 but you use Qt 5.5.1, is the error not clear?

Comment: but if i compile this project using a version above 5.5 then this error occors

Comment: Please, learn how to format the code or error message: 1. Paste the code into the question post. 2. Select the pasted code. 3. Press `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button. Or put ``` before and after the code. When you edit the post, resulted content is shown below the edit area. Please, check that content while you are editing.

Comment: The last error message has "Possible reasons include" part, not sure why do you omit it in the question post. This is actual description of possible reasons for the error. In short: you QT installation under `C:\Qt\Qt5.13.2\5.13.2\mingw73_32\` seems to be **broken**.